# Dimension of functions as a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

```
V3 = Fun(F^2,F) for F = Z/2Z
V4 = Fun(F^2,F) for F = R
```

What are dim V3 and dim V4?

I'm thinking for V3, Fun(F^2,F)=Fun({(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)},F)=F^4, so dim V3 = 4.
Not sure if this is correct. And I'm confused how to determine dim V4.

Could anyone explain? Thank you!

Comment: Unusual notation. Does “Fun” mean linear functions?

Comment: Your calculation is correct. Now, if $Fun$ stands for Function or linear Function the dimension of $V_4$ is always infinity. In fact the first case contain all linear function and in this case the vector space is given by the matrix $1\times2$.